# Examples of isomorphic group presentations with homotopy NONequivalent complexes

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_complex)) A *presentation complex* is a 2-dimensional cell complex associated to any presentation of a group $G$. The complex has a single vertex, and one loop at the vertex for each generator of $G$. There is one 2-cell for each relation in the presentation, with the boundary of the 2-cell attached along the appropriate word.

A group $G$ can be presented in different ways. These presentations need not have homotopy equivalent presentation complexes. **I would like to collect as many examples of presentations of a group with presentation complexes that are not homotopy equivalent as possible.** I would take the following as sufficient answers to this post:

1. Referrals to references which have such examples, or discuss methods to construct such presentations;
2. Examples of such presentations, preferably a large number of them, and preferably not all sharing many common threads (in, say, how they are constructed, dimension, etc.).

The motivation for my question is that I am interested in so-called *exotic group presentations*. See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.10786.pdf) for some info on them.

Comment: I don't know of any examples where the complexes are obviously not homotopy equivalent.  For example in the $Q_{28}$ paper that you cited, it is easy to see that one presentation has $\pi_2$ generated by a single element, whilst the other $\pi_2$ decomposes in such a way that if it were generated by a single element, the image of the map of units  $$\mathbb{H}\supset\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/7},j]^*\to \mathbb{F}_7[j]^*,\qquad e^{2\pi i/7}\mapsto -1$$ contains $1+j$.    This is not the case: a subtle number theoretic result in Swan's 106 page paper: Projective modules over binary polyhedral groups.

Comment: Actually, there is an elementary argument for the number theoretic result above - see my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4250386/units-in-the-cyclotomic-ring-of-degree-7/4257895#4257895.  Thus this example can be understood with just a basic background in algebraic topology and some elementary algebra.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take
$$G=\langle x,y\mid x^2=y^3\rangle.$$
This is the standard presentation for the fundamental group of the trefoil knot. Of note is the fact that this group is Hopfian and non polycyclic-by-finite.

Now for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ put
$$G_n=\langle x,y,\overline x,\overline y\mid x^2=y^3,\overline x^2=\overline y^3,x^{2n+1}=\overline x^{2n+1},y^{3n+1}=\overline y^{3n+1}\rangle.$$
The result in each case is a different presentation of $G$. Write $K_n$ for the presentation complex corresponding to $G_n$. Using the fact that the commutator group of $\pi_1K_n\cong G_n\cong G$ is free of rank $2$, and that $G/[G,G]\cong\mathbb{Z}$ you can show without too much difficulty that that $\chi(K_n)=1$ for each $n$.

> There are infinitely many distinct homotopy types amongst the $K_n$.

This may be established by studying the homologies of the universal covering spaces $\widetilde K_n$. It can be shown that there are infinitely many integers $m,n$ such that $H_2(\widetilde K_m;\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_2(\widetilde K_n;\mathbb{Z})$ are non-isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules. An interesting fact is that $K_m\vee S^2\simeq K_n\vee S^2$ although $K_m\not\simeq K_n$.

The calculations for all this are contained in *Exotic relation modules and homotopy types for certain 1–relator groups*, Algr. Geo. Top. **6**, 2163-2173, (2006), by J. Harlander, J. Jensen. They make use of ealier work by P. Berridge and M. Dunwoody in the paper *Non‐Free Projective Modules for Torsion‐Free Groups* J. London Math. Soc. **2**, 433–436, (1979).

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Do you know off the top of your head if many examples are known? Do you know of any examples where the complexes are *obviously* not homotopy equivalent?

Comment: @DescartesBeforetheHorse there are other examples but the trefoil is the simplest I know. I don't know if there is a systematic way of producing interesting examples. Short of implementing Tietze transforms that add or remove redunant relations I don't know of any more subtle but still 'obvious' examples.

Comment: A question. Did you mean $H^2$? As far as I've studied, I've only ever seen $H_2$ used to refer to homologies, whereas I have only seen $H^2$ to refer to cohomologies.

Comment: I think rather that I meant *homologies*.

Comment: (+1) "Using the fact that the commutator group of $\pi_1K_n\cong G_n\cong G$ is free of rank $2$, and that $G/[G,G]\cong\mathbb{Z}$ you can show without too much difficulty that that $\chi(K_n)=1$ for each $n$." $${}$$ Or count the = signs in the presentation: $\chi(K_n)=4-4+1=1$.