# Units in the cyclotomic ring of degree $7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i \over 7}$.  Given $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$, show that:
$$ u\bar{u}+v\bar{v}\,\,\text{ is a  unit }\implies (1-\zeta)\mid uv. $$

**Motivation** An equivalent form of this result is often used to demonstrate various phenomena in low dimensional topology (see my comment on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057186/examples-of-isomorphic-group-presentations-with-homotopy-nonequivalent-complexes).  Note "$\zeta\mapsto -1$" is a typo and should be  "$\zeta\mapsto 1$").  As mentioned in the comment, authors usually cite this as a special case of part of a calculation buried [deep](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0342?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B114%5D,%22panX%22:0.634,%22panY%22:0.79,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.8%7D) in a $106$ page paper.

**Attempted approach** If one could find criteria for elements of the form $u\bar{u}\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}]$, with $ u\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ and there was a nice description of the units in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}]$, one might be able to obtain a constraint on expressing them as the sum of two elements satisfying the criterion. However $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ is a unit with infinite multiplicative order, and it is not clear what a nice description of the units might be.

---

**Update** A search through all "small" $u,v$ found that every time that $u\bar{u}+v\bar{v}$ is a unit, we have $uv=0$.  Here "small" means expressible as a linear combination of $1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\cdots,\zeta^6$ with coefficients differing by at most $5$.  It therefore seems reasonable to conjecture the stronger statement:$$ u\bar{u}+v\bar{v}\,\,\text{ is a  unit }\implies uv=0, $$ which may be easier to prove.

Comment: are there partial classifications of the units in the rings $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta], \mathbb{Z}[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}]$?

Comment: We have powers of $\zeta$ and the cyclotomic units generated by $$1+\zeta,\quad 1+\zeta+\zeta^2,\quad 1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3,\quad 1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4,\quad 1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4+\zeta^5,\quad 1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4+\zeta^5+\zeta^6.$$  I think this may be all the units, as $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is a PID ($7<23$), but I may be misremembering something that I possibly misread in the first place, about the index of cyclotomic units in all units being related to the class number.

Comment: What about the other ring $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}]$ - are some units known? Is this ring the ring of integers of a number field $K$?

Comment: Here $1+\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ is a unit, as is $2+\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$, just by taking the ones I mentioned before and multiplying by a suitable power of $\zeta$ to "balance" them.    This ring is the ring of integers of a cubic number field: $\mathbb{Q}[w]/\langle w^3+w^2-2w-1\rangle $

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta,\zeta^{-1}]=\mathcal{O}_K$ you "know" the units $\mathcal{O}_K^*$ by the Dirichlet unit theorem. Are you saying there is no explicit "basis" for $\mathcal{O}_K^*$?

Comment: If $K$ is a number field, the DUT says there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_K^* \cong \mu(K) \oplus \mathbb{Z}\{e_1,..,e_{r+s-1}\}$, hence you must calculate a basis $e_i$ for the units in the case of $p(t):=t^3+t^2-2t-1 \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$.

Comment: In general the subgroup generated by the cyclotomic units is only of a finite index in the full group of units of $\mathcal{O}_K^*$, where $K=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_unit) says that the index is equal to the class number of $K$, which is good news here. I'm afraid that result is beyond me, but I would think WP is accurate here. I'm just a student of algebraic number theory (though I have attempted to apply it elsewhere on a few occasions).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - What are you saying? Are you claiming that there is no isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_K^* \cong \mu(K) \oplus \mathbb{Z}\{e_1,..,e_{r+s-1}\}$?

Comment: @hm2020 That result from Wikipedia is about certain *specific choices* of $e_i$s. Or, whether we can choose, for example,
$e_1=\zeta^{-1}+1+\zeta$, $e_2=\zeta^3+\zeta^4$ both of which are real units of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$. I do not know whether the WP result says that we can specify those cyclotomic units that generate a subgroup of the unit group of this prescribed index, or whether we need to take all of them. Cyclotomic units, that is, numbers of the form $\zeta^j(1-\zeta^k)/(1-\zeta^\ell)$, $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/m}$, $k,\ell$ both coprime to $m$, are easy to describe.

Comment: (cont'd) How large a fraction of the full group of units they cover is the more delicate question I am unable to say anything about. I do know that the index is finite.

Comment: @hm2020 It looks like $r=3,s=0$: $w\mapsto w, w^2-2, w^3-3w$ all real, so the units of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}]$ are generated by a pair of elements plus torsion (possibly the ones suggested by @JyrkiLahtonen).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - yes it seems one must calculate two "fundamental units" $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ and one gets $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta,\zeta^{-1}]^* \cong \mu(K) \oplus \epsilon_1^{n}\epsilon_2^m$ with $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ as the group of units. This shouldnt be too difficult - has anyone done it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be much simpler than I thought.

Suppose $u\bar{u}+v\bar{v}$ is a unit with $u,v\in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ both non-zero.  We will draw a contradiction.

Let $*\colon \mathbb{Z}[\zeta] \to \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ be the automorphism mapping $\zeta\mapsto \zeta^2$.  Any $x\in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ can be written as a linear combination of $1,\zeta,\cdots, \zeta^6$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.  If $x=x^*$ and $x=\bar{x}$ then its coefficients on $\zeta,\cdots, \zeta^6$ must be equal and we have $x\in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $u\bar{u}+v\bar{v}$ is a unit then so are $(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})^*$ and $(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})^{**}$, so the product of all three:
$$(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})^*(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})^{**},$$
is a unit too.

The elements $$(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})^*(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})^{**},\qquad (u\bar{u})(u\bar{u})^*(u\bar{u})^{**},\qquad (v\bar{v})(v\bar{v})^*(v\bar{v})^{**},$$ are all integers, as they are invariant under $*$ and complex conjugation.  Further they are all positive integers, as they are each the product of three positive real numbers.  Thus $$(u\bar{u})(u\bar{u})^*(u\bar{u})^{**},\, (v\bar{v})(v\bar{v})^*(v\bar{v})^{**}\geq 1.\qquad\qquad(1)$$

The only positive integer unit is $1$, so $$(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})^*(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})^{**}=1.$$

Expanding we get: \begin{eqnarray*}1&=&(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})^*(u\bar{u}+v\bar{v})^{**}\\
&=&(u\bar{u})(u\bar{u})^*(u\bar{u})^{**}\left(1+\frac{v\bar{v}}{u\bar{u}}+\frac{(v\bar{v})^*}{(u\bar{u})^*}+\frac{(v\bar{v})^{**}}{(u\bar{u})^{**}}\right)\\&+&(v\bar{v})(v\bar{v})^*(v\bar{v})^{**}\left(1+\frac{u\bar{u}}{v\bar{v}}+\frac{(u\bar{u})^{*}}{(v\bar{v})^{*}}+\frac{(u\bar{u})^{**}}{(v\bar{v})^{**}}\right)\\&\geq&1\cdot1+1\cdot 1=2.
\end{eqnarray*}

We have attained our desired contradiction $1\geq 2$.